# Pintar Columnas dinámicas con jqxGrid Jquery Jason Asp.net C# WebForms 3 capas

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net

hola comuniad espero me puedan ayudar con esto:

Estoy tratando de cargar columnas de forma dinamica (sin declararlas) usando jqxGrid de Jquery mas Jason. Aqui les muestro lo que tengo.

Hasta aqui todo marcha bien no marca error en mi webMethod

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string ListarPersonas()
    {


        Operaciones t = new Operaciones();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = t.Listar_Personas(1,"",1);
        string datos = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.Indented);
        return datos;

    }
```

Este es mi Script de javascript y hasta aqui tambien es correcto ya que me marca mi alerta alert("Entro correcto OK");

```
function obtener_intervalo() {

var id_Persona = 1;
var Trabajo = "";
var id_Usuario = 1;


if (id_Persona != 0) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "frmPersonas.aspx/ListarPersonas",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: '{id_Persona:"'+id_Persona+'",Trabajo:"'+Trabajo+'",ROl:"'+id_Usuario+'"}',

        success: function(data) {
            alert("Entro correcto Ok");
            Datasourcefuncion(data.d);               
        },

        error: function(error) {
            alert(error.responseText);
            console.log(error.responseText);
            jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(Error.responseText);
            alert(error.respose.Text);
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
else 
    alert("error en id_Persona");
    return false;


}
```

Mi problema es como pintar esas columnas que sean dinámicas con este control jqxGrid sin tener que declarar el nombre de mis columnas. Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: que seria "pintar" quieres aplicar un estilo de colores ?

Comment: Hola Leandro quiere que me muestra como tal el gridView con el nombre de columnas que estan declaradas en mi base de datos sin tener que declararlas. Gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Analizando el codigo que publicas no recomendaria que uses `DataTable` para serializar a json, no es buena idea.

Deberias declarar una clase como ser

```
public class Persona{
    public string Nombre {get;set;}
    public string Edad {get;set;}
    //otras propiedades
}
```

entonces eso es lo que retornas como respuestas del `webmethod`

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<Persona> string ListarPersonas()
{
    Operaciones t = new Operaciones();
    List<Persona> personas = t.Listar_Personas(1,"",1);

    return personas;
}
```

como observsra sno necesitas serializar ya que al usar `ResponseFormat.Json` lo hara automaticamente

Esta e sla mejor forma de enviar datos como json al cliente

Comment: Hola Leandro estoy de acuerdo pero en ese aspecto no tengo problema ya que de igual forma me retorna los datos y se comunica con mi script. Mi problema es que no se como mostrar el nombre y numero de columnas dinamicamente en mi jqxGrid las cuales tengo en mi base de datos. Gracias nuevamente por tu ayuda.

Comment: nombre y numero de columnas dinamicas ? si usas clases y listas no hay nada dinamico tienes que respectar una estructura de informacion que se serializa a json. Si usaste el DataTable para que sea dinamico es pesima idea porque este no serializa bien a json

Comment: Ok Leandro te entiendo muy bien. Volviendo al mi problema. Sabes alguna solucion para mostrar un jxqGrid de Jquery con columnas dinamicas a traves de json y jquery. en asp.net. Es decir un grid con columnas dondo si yo agrego otra columna en mi base de datos la aplicacion me la muestre sin problemas.De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: si agregas una columna en la db, vas a tener que agregar la propiedad que mapee con esa columna en la class, asi se envia como parte dle json, no conozco mucho de `jxqGrid`, pero si tiene la opcion que genere columnas dinamicas como lo hace el `GridView` cuando usas el AutoGenereteColumns entonce mostrara lo que envies en el json